# How to share a string between two processes containing while loops?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I've been struggling for a while trying to pass a variable between two processes,

I have two processes, one that loops to run a PyQt5 GUI (process A), and a second running some computer vision functions on a video stream in real-time through a while loop (process B),

I want to read a constantly updated (30 times a second) variable from B to A, latency up to ~200ms doesn't matter too much.

Process A will make changes to the GUI based on the var passed from Process B but I'm struggling to pass that variable across,

I've attached some skeleton code that shows my current broken attempt, I have reread the docs several times and a load of questions on here but I'm new to multiprocessing so I'm a bit stumped, I would really appreciate if someone could take a look and point me in the right direction,
Thanks!

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
from ctypes import c_wchar_p  # c_wchar_p
from time import sleep

def processA(sharedMessageA):
    while True:                               # set up and render GUI
        if sharedMessageA.value == "Left":     # Read shared variable from ProcessB and do things
            print("Lbutton")
        elif sharedMessageA.value == "Right":
            print("Rbutton")

def processB(sharedMessageB):
    while True:
        sleep(0.05)                    # get video stream and performs various computer vision functions
        sharedMessageB.value = "Left"   # write result of functions to variable for process A to use

def startMultiProcessing():
    p1 = Process(target=processA, args=(sharedMessage,))
    p2 = Process(target=processB, args=(sharedMessage,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()

def main():
    startMultiProcessing()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    sharedMessage = manager.Value(c_wchar_p, "Test") # initialise shared value
    main()
```

Comment: Philosophically, this is not a good plan.  Multiprocessing only really works well when the processes are independent.  You can use a pair of `multiprocessing.Queue` structures for this, or you can use a TCP socket (which is probably what Queue uses under the covers).  `multiprocessing.Queue` and `queue.Queue` are both very handy data structures that don't get the love they deserve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong with your program?  It appears to work fine - from parameter passing point of view at least.  I tweaked your code a bit (added a random choice and added sleep to the main process to avoid it exiting right away) and it seems to be doing fine:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
from ctypes import c_wchar_p  # c_wchar_p
from time import sleep
import random

def processA(sharedMessageA):
    while True:                               # set up and render GUI
        sleep(0.01)
        if sharedMessageA.value == "Left":     # Read shared variable from ProcessB and do things
            print("Lbutton")
        elif sharedMessageA.value == "Right":
            print("Rbutton")

def processB(sharedMessageB):
    while True:
        sleep(0.05)                    # get video stream and performs various computer vision functions
        sharedMessageB.value = random.choice(["Left", "Right"])   # write result of functions to variable for process A to use

def startMultiProcessing():
    p1 = Process(target=processA, args=(sharedMessage,))
    p2 = Process(target=processB, args=(sharedMessage,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()

def main():
    startMultiProcessing()
    sleep(30)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    sharedMessage = manager.Value(c_wchar_p, "Test") # initialise shared value
    main()
```

Now when I run this, I get random "button" messages as is expected:

```
test@test:~$ python3 foo.py 
Lbutton
Lbutton
Lbutton
Lbutton
Lbutton
Rbutton
Rbutton
Rbutton
Rbutton
Rbutton
Rbutton
Rbutton
Rbutton
Rbutton
Rbutton
Rbutton
Rbutton
Rbutton
Rbutton
Lbutton
Lbutton
Lbutton
```

Whatever the problem is, it is not in passing the string between processes. You have done that part correctly.

NB as you are passing a simple element, you could improve performance by switching to shared memory but that might not be important in your case.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, Yeah you're right when I compared it to the actual program I was calling the parent name of the variable, not the local name for that process, my bad, I think i'd been working on it too long , Thanks though I was ready to give up :)